# C# base directory access denied

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read a text file for my program. When debugging, using

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"text files", path);
```

works fine, but when I run the .exe file I get

> Access to the path: '' is denied

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and also show the actual code that is **doing the file access**. The `Path.Combine()` that you included only combines some strings into a new string, and thus cannot produce the error you say is occurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be possible that exe is open in task manager. See the process is open or not 
if open write the code below to stop the process.

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("abc.exe");

if (processes.Length > 0)
    processes[0].CloseMainWindow();
```